# Few questions about android TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I'm new in android and I have few questions to ask.

1. Is it possible to use the keypad (Left and Right) to move from one TabHost to another?
2. I successfully changed the selector color in listview, then how can I change the text
   color in ListView as well?
3. Is it possible change the TabHost layout by own graphics?
4. I have created a TabHost aligned to the bottom of the screen. How can I move the "line" on bottom of TabWidget to above? (see screenshot)

[alt text http://desmond.yfrog.com/Himg251/scaled.php?tn=0&server=251&filename=tabwidget.png&xsize=640&ysize=640](http://desmond.yfrog.com/Himg251/scaled.php?tn=0&server=251&filename=tabwidget.png&xsize=640&ysize=640)

Your reply is very appreciated.
Thank you.

P/S: sorry about my bad english, hope you guys understand what I'm talking about.
Thanks

Comment: Anyone have idea to fix it? may I ask another question? Is it possible I override the tab function? for example I need add some animation when the user selected the TabWidget? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3/ yes it's possible and if you use your own graphics like this, you will have a picture insidetab

```
int tab_list_on;
private TabHost mTabHost;

mTabHost = getTabHost();

tab_list_on = R.drawable.onglet_480_liste;
TabImgFond1 = new ImageView(this, null, android.graphics.Typeface.NORMAL);
TabImgFond1.setImageResource(tab_list_on);

mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_LISTE).setIndicator(TabImgFond1).setContent(intentList));

mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    TabChangedState(tabId);
    }
});
mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

1/you can try this, i'm not sure, but i think it's working, put this inside your class

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
Log.i(TAG,"CODE : "+keyCode);
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
    //TODO
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```